# ESLint says array never modified even though elements are pushed into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am converting some existing code to follow ECMA script and I am using ESLint to follow a coding standard.  I have the following ecmascript method

```
static getArrayOfIndices(text, char) {
    let resultArray = [];
    let index = text.indexOf(char);
    const lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf(char);
    while (index <= lastIndex && index !== -1) {
      resultArray.push(index);
      if (index < lastIndex) {
        index = text.substr(index + 1).indexOf(char) + index + 1;
      } else {
        index = lastIndex + 1999; // some random addition to fail test condition on next iteration
      }
    }
    return resultArray;
  }
```

For the declaration of resultArray, ESLint throws the error

```
ESLint: `resultArray` is never modified, use `const`instead. (prefer-const)
```

But since elements are being pushed into the array, isn't it being modified?

Comment: But it stays the same array object, so the pointer to that object is a constant.

Comment: Ah! Even though the contents of the object may change, the reference /pointer to that object remains the same so it is preferred to use const. If the  reference was being changed, e.g. resultArray = someOtherArray, then using let would be fine. Got it!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To understand this error you must understand that `const` declared variables hold read-only references to a value. But it does not mean that the value it holds is immutable [[mdn article]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Since you are only changing members of the variable, but not performing a reassignment on the binding the `prefer-const` rule of es-lint warns you that a `const` declared variable could be used instead of a `let` declared variable.

Comment: Thanks..! It was helpful

Comment: I didn't know that `const` meant that the reference is read-only but that the entity it pointed to was mutable. Is this a peculiarity of JS or do other major programming languages share this concept for `const`? I can see how it can be easily misunderstood if you don't know the implementation details of `const`. Really interesting and it makes sense one you read the article.

Comment: @10110 This is common across several major programming languages. For example `final` variables in Java, `val` in Kotlin and `readonly` in C# work the same way. Other languages like PHP and Go only allow you to have certain immutable types in `const` variables, like strings, ints etc., so the concept wouldn't be relevant in those.